# Enabling crash logs symbolication in Xcode 4.2

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, xcode4.2

I am using Xcode 4.2 and my crash logs are not getting symbolicated. How to enable this in Xcode 4.2?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Please Go through the [Apple's Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2151/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008184-CH1-SECTION2) for More Details.

The above Apple's Link contains explanation of what I am displaying in crash reports settings image and how to use crash report to symolicate the hexadecimal values.

Now the following things you should take care to generate crash report while building your application.

In xcode  project navigator click on your project and then click on the Build Settings. When you archive your application, xcode uses the release Configuration by default, you will want to set the following values for the Release Configuration only..

Ensure the following values are set for Release Configuration.

[image]

Once these values are set, Archive and reinstall your application.Now crash reports are generated from the  resulting archive should be symbolicated.

This is specifically for xcode 4.

Answer (score 10):

If its not in there already, drag the crash log into the "Device Logs" section of the "Devices" tab in the organizer window:

[image]

*if the App that crashed was built **without** stripping debug symbols*:

[image]

a nice symbolicated crash log will appear:

[image]

This screenshot shows a crash log of my App that had symbol strip set to YES when it was built, but if you set strip symbols to NO, these lines will also symbolicate properly.

Comment: This worked for me though, in XCode 4.5, I couldn't get drag to work, so I just used IMPORT those crash logs.