# How to symbolicate the crash log to know the exact location of crash?

Tags: iphone

I have .dsym,.app,.crash files.but don't know where we have to put all these files to symbolicate the crash log.even i don't know the exact process.I have googled but did not found any satisfactory answer.Any help would be appreciated.Thanx

Comment: Please go to my answer in the previous post. This will everytime creates a symbolic crash reports on your device which will really be helpful to debug your code. (other answer on same post also indicates the good point but its a long way of doing) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7932992/enabling-crash-logs-symbolication-in-xcode-4-2/7937300#7937300

Answer (score 0):

It uses spotlight indexing, so you can put it anywhere...
check out this answer [Symbolicating iPhone App Crash Reports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1460892/symbolicating-iphone-app-crash-reports)

Comment: I m using xcode 3.2.6.and when i put my crash file in organizer then it only shows the binary codes.But i want to know the exact class and exact location of crash so that i can remove it.

Comment: did you checked all answers on that thread? There is also step by step how to symbolicate from command line

Comment: yeah.I have checked but did not getting the perfect way.even i have followed the process through terminal.But after reaching to the directory where i kept all these files i use the command to read crash report using symbolicate command.but it returns symboliacet command not found

Answer (score 0):

Since Xcode uses spotlight to find the .dSYM and application files that match the crash log, it will need a few moments to index those files if you have just copied them to your Mac.

When you put crash logs into Xcode, it may take a little time to symbolicate.  In Xcode 4, it can take a minute to find everything and symbolicate for me.

The application executable may need to be pulled out of the .ipa file.  You can do this by adding ".zip" to the file name, then opening it. Pull the executable from the "Payload" folder and put it in the same folder as the dSYM file.

To find out if a .dSYM file matches a crash log, check their UUID numbers. In terminal, use 
dwarfdump -u 
Compare the resulting number to the number shown with the executable in the "Binary Images" section of the crash log.