# App running on iPhone 3GS with ios4, but not in a iPhone 4 with iOS 5.0.1

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, app-store-connect

I have develop an iOS 4 app with latest SDK and XCode 4.2.

I have tested on my iPhone 3GS with iOs 4.3.5 and on Simulator and it works! But now, I have sent it to review and it has been rejected because it crashes on an iPhone 4 with iOS 5.0.1.

They have said that:

**We found that your app crashed on launch while installed on iPhone 4 running iOS 5.0.1**

This is the crash log:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>AutoSubmitted</key>
    <true/>
    <key>SysInfoCrashReporterKey</key>
    <string>b46ed4c9a3547574ffc93e0841c55f1097ba4371</string>
    <key>bug_type</key>
    <string>109</string>
    <key>description</key>
    <string>Incident Identifier: F3CE50AF-D164-4C60-BE4D-65D7F42E5226
CrashReporter Key:   b46ed4c9a3547574ffc93e0841c55f1097ba4371
Hardware Model:      iPhone3,1
Process:         Tarot [5670]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/C9491EAA-4064-4884-8349-334DC1EE87DF/Tarot.app/Tarot
Identifier:      Tarot
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2012-01-13 10:58:14.166 -0800
OS Version:      iPhone OS 5.0.1 (9A405)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x00000000, 0x00000000
Crashed Thread:  0

Last Exception Backtrace:
(0x342ca8bf 0x3451a1e5 0x342ca7b9 0x342ca7db 0x378e7747 0x378579cb 0x37736ea1 0x376ac78b 0x376d0f51 0x376956a5 0x377580e5 0x3769de51 0x3769de6d 0x3769dcff 0x3769dcdb 0x233b 0x376ab7eb 0x376a53bd 0x37673921 0x376733bf 0x37672d2d 0x30aa5df3 0x3429e553 0x3429e4f5 0x3429d343 0x342204dd 0x342203a5 0x376a4457 0x376a1743 0x20a7 0x2040)

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x361e532c 0x361d4000 + 70444
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x330aef54 0x33061000 + 319316
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x330a7fe4 0x33061000 + 290788
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x336f1f64 0x336eb000 + 28516
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x336ef346 0x336eb000 + 17222
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3451a2dc 0x34511000 + 37596
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x336ef3be 0x336eb000 + 17342
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x336ef44a 0x336eb000 + 17482
8   libc++abi.dylib                 0x336f081e 0x336eb000 + 22558
9   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3451a22e 0x34511000 + 37422
10  CoreFoundation                  0x3422053e 0x34211000 + 62782
11  CoreFoundation                  0x3422039e 0x34211000 + 62366
12  UIKit                           0x376a4450 0x37670000 + 214096
13  UIKit                           0x376a173c 0x37670000 + 202556
14  Tarot                           0x000020a0 0x1000 + 4256
15  Tarot                           0x00002038 0x1000 + 4152

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x361d53b4 0x361d4000 + 5044
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x36effe78 0x36ef3000 + 52856
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x36effb96 0x36ef3000 + 52118

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x361e5cd4 0x361d4000 + 72916
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3306b30a 0x33061000 + 41738
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3306b09c 0x33061000 + 41116

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x361e5cd4 0x361d4000 + 72916
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3306b30a 0x33061000 + 41738
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3306b09c 0x33061000 + 41116

Thread 4 name:  WebThread
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x361d5010 0x361d4000 + 4112
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x361d5206 0x361d4000 + 4614
2   CoreFoundation                  0x3429e41c 0x34211000 + 578588
3   CoreFoundation                  0x3429d154 0x34211000 + 573780
4   CoreFoundation                  0x342204d6 0x34211000 + 62678
5   CoreFoundation                  0x3422039e 0x34211000 + 62366
6   WebCore                         0x366f4128 0x3664c000 + 688424
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33070c16 0x33061000 + 64534
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33070ad0 0x33061000 + 64208

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State:
    r0: 0x00000000    r1: 0x00000000      r2: 0x00000001      r3: 0x00000000
    r4: 0x00000006    r5: 0x3e998ce8      r6: 0x00000002      r7: 0x2fdffa70
    r8: 0x3fc3cdec    r9: 0x336f2a4a     r10: 0x00141140     r11: 0x3fc4863c
    ip: 0x00000148    sp: 0x2fdffa64      lr: 0x330aef5b      pc: 0x361e532c
  cpsr: 0x00000010

Binary Images:
    0x1000 -     0x7fff +Tarot armv7  &lt;c7e3c083432a3060ac78f8c06c91c3ec&gt; /var/mobile/Applications/C9491EAA-4064-4884-8349-334DC1EE87DF/Tarot.app/Tarot
0x2fefc000 - 0x2ff1dfff  dyld armv7  &lt;be7c0b491a943054ad12eb5060f1da06&gt; 
0x37c5a000 - 0x37c5afff  libunwind.dylib armv7  &lt;d21222aad8c93d6c9580f9bf47071946&gt; /usr/lib/system/libunwind.dylib
</string>
    <key>displayName</key>
    <string>Tarot</string>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>Tarot</string>
    <key>os_version</key>
    <string>iPhone OS 5.0.1 (9A405)</string>
    <key>system_ID</key>
    <string></string>
    <key>version</key>
    <string>??? (???)</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

**UPDATE**
This is the crash symbolicated:

```
    Incident Identifier: F3CE50AF-D164-4C60-BE4D-65D7F42E5226
    CrashReporter Key:   b46ed4c9a3547574ffc93e0841c55f1097ba4371
    Hardware Model:      iPhone3,1
    Process:         Tarot [5670]
    Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/C9491EAA-4064-4884-8349-334DC1EE87DF/Tarot.app/Tarot
    Identifier:      Tarot
    Version:         ??? (???)
    Code Type:       ARM (Native)
    Parent Process:  launchd [1]

    Date/Time:       2012-01-13 10:58:14.166 -0800
    OS Version:      iPhone OS 5.0.1 (9A405)
    Report Version:  104

    Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
    Exception Codes: 0x00000000, 0x00000000
    Crashed Thread:  0

    Last Exception Backtrace:
    0   CoreFoundation                  0x342ca8bf 0x34211000 + 759999
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3451a1e5 0x34511000 + 37349
    2   CoreFoundation                  0x342ca7b9 0x34211000 + 759737
    3   CoreFoundation                  0x342ca7db 0x34211000 + 759771
    4   UIKit                           0x378e7747 0x37670000 + 2586439
    5   UIKit                           0x378579cb 0x37670000 + 1997259
    6   UIKit                           0x37736ea1 0x37670000 + 814753
    7   UIKit                           0x376ac78b 0x37670000 + 247691
    8   UIKit                           0x376d0f51 0x37670000 + 397137
    9   UIKit                           0x376956a5 0x37670000 + 153253
    10  UIKit                           0x377580e5 0x37670000 + 950501
    11  UIKit                           0x3769de51 0x37670000 + 187985
    12  UIKit                           0x3769de6d 0x37670000 + 188013
    13  UIKit                           0x3769dcff 0x37670000 + 187647
    14  UIKit                           0x3769dcdb 0x37670000 + 187611
    15  Tarot                           0x0000233b -[AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] (AppDelegate.m:46)
    16  UIKit                           0x376ab7eb 0x37670000 + 243691
    17  UIKit                           0x376a53bd 0x37670000 + 218045
    18  UIKit                           0x37673921 0x37670000 + 14625
    19  UIKit                           0x376733bf 0x37670000 + 13247
    20  UIKit                           0x37672d2d 0x37670000 + 11565
    21  GraphicsServices                0x30aa5df3 0x30aa1000 + 19955
    22  CoreFoundation                  0x3429e553 0x34211000 + 578899
    23  CoreFoundation                  0x3429e4f5 0x34211000 + 578805
    24  CoreFoundation                  0x3429d343 0x34211000 + 574275
    25  CoreFoundation                  0x342204dd 0x34211000 + 62685
    26  CoreFoundation                  0x342203a5 0x34211000 + 62373
    27  UIKit                           0x376a4457 0x37670000 + 214103
    28  UIKit                           0x376a1743 0x37670000 + 202563
    29  Tarot                           0x000020a7 main (main.m:16)
    30  Tarot                           0x00002040 0x1000 + 4160


    Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
    Thread 0 Crashed:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x361e532c 0x361d4000 + 70444
    1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x330aef54 0x33061000 + 319316
    2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x330a7fe4 0x33061000 + 290788
    3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x336f1f64 abort_message + 40
    4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x336ef346 default_terminate() + 18
    5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3451a2dc 0x34511000 + 37596
    6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x336ef3be safe_handler_caller(void (*)()) + 70
    7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x336ef44a std::terminate() + 14
    8   libc++abi.dylib                 0x336f081e __cxa_rethrow + 82
    9   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3451a22e 0x34511000 + 37422
    10  CoreFoundation                  0x3422053e 0x34211000 + 62782
    11  CoreFoundation                  0x3422039e 0x34211000 + 62366
    12  UIKit                           0x376a4450 0x37670000 + 214096
    13  UIKit                           0x376a173c 0x37670000 + 202556
    14  Tarot                           0x000020a0 main (main.m:16)
    15  Tarot                           0x00002038 0x1000 + 4152

    Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
    Thread 1:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x361d53b4 0x361d4000 + 5044
    1   libdispatch.dylib               0x36effe78 0x36ef3000 + 52856
    2   libdispatch.dylib               0x36effb96 0x36ef3000 + 52118

    Thread 2:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x361e5cd4 0x361d4000 + 72916
    1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3306b30a 0x33061000 + 41738
    2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3306b09c 0x33061000 + 41116

    Thread 3:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x361e5cd4 0x361d4000 + 72916
    1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3306b30a 0x33061000 + 41738
    2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3306b09c 0x33061000 + 41116

    Thread 4 name:  WebThread
    Thread 4:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x361d5010 0x361d4000 + 4112
    1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x361d5206 0x361d4000 + 4614
    2   CoreFoundation                  0x3429e41c 0x34211000 + 578588
    3   CoreFoundation                  0x3429d154 0x34211000 + 573780
    4   CoreFoundation                  0x342204d6 0x34211000 + 62678
    5   CoreFoundation                  0x3422039e 0x34211000 + 62366
    6   WebCore                         0x366f4128 0x3664c000 + 688424
    7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33070c16 0x33061000 + 64534
    8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33070ad0 0x33061000 + 64208

    Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State:
        r0: 0x00000000    r1: 0x00000000      r2: 0x00000001      r3: 0x00000000
        r4: 0x00000006    r5: 0x3e998ce8      r6: 0x00000002      r7: 0x2fdffa70
        r8: 0x3fc3cdec    r9: 0x336f2a4a     r10: 0x00141140     r11: 0x3fc4863c
        ip: 0x00000148    sp: 0x2fdffa64      lr: 0x330aef5b      pc: 0x361e532c
      cpsr: 0x00000010

    Binary Images:
        0x1000 -     0x7fff +Tarot armv7  <c7e3c083432a3060ac78f8c06c91c3ec> 
...
    0x37c5a000 - 0x37c5afff  libunwind.dylib armv7  <d21222aad8c93d6c9580f9bf47071946> /usr/lib/system/libunwind.dylib
```

**UPDATE END**
I don't know how to deal with this. I think  it could be a problem with a navcontroller that I have added manually. This is the code:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class ViewController;
@class OneCardViewController;
@class ThreeCardsViewController;
@class AboutViewController;

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>
{
    UINavigationController* navController;
    ViewController* viewController;
    OneCardViewController* oneCardViewController;
    ThreeCardsViewController* threeCardsViewController;
    AboutViewController* aboutViewController;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property (strong, nonatomic) ViewController *viewController;
```

**UPDATE**
The first line posted here is line 17 on XCode editor.

**UPDATE END**
And M file:

```
@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize window = _window;
@synthesize viewController;

- (void)dealloc
{
    [_window release];

    [navController release];
    [viewController release];
    [oneCardViewController release];
    [threeCardsViewController release];
    [aboutViewController release];

    [super dealloc];
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
    viewController.title = @"Menu";
    navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController];
    navController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];

    self.window.rootViewController = navController;

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Can you help me, please?

**UPDATE**
It seems to have a problem with this line:

```
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Comment: Please post symbolicated last exception backtrace.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what is the symbolicated last exception backtrace.

Comment: The crash report includes "Last Exception Backtrace". You can use `atos` command line tool to convert the addresses to human-readable function names.

Comment: Thanks. I will do it, but I don't how much time it will take (is the first time I do that). Thanks, again.

Comment: You can also try dragging the crash report into Xcode organizer. Xcode should symbolicate it automagically.

Comment: They have sent me four files with these names: Tarot_2012-01-13-105808_October4thiOS5.plist. Where can I drag these files? Organizer has the following sub-views: Devices, Repositories, Projects, Archives and Documentation. May I have to change crash file name? Because I drag it over Organizer and nothing happens.

Comment: I've added symbolicated log to my question as an update.

Comment: Unfortunately, Xcode did not find the symbol files for iOS 5.0.1. Your code looks OK though, so the problem is most likely with the ViewController.nib.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem appears to lie in your ViewController code, or it's NIB. Look in that class's `viewWillAppear:` and `viewDidAppear:`. In the NIB, look for any missing referenced files (such as image views missing images).

Unfortunately, to have not posted that code so further help is limited.
But .. Why'd don't you upgrade your 3GS to iOS5 to debug the problem?

Answer (score 0):

When you build your app using Xcode's "Build for Archiving" command, the debug symbols file should be automatically generated and stored. This symbols file can be used to "symbolicate" crash log files, which makes it possible to read such files and figure out what caused the crash. Drag the log file that Apple sent you into the Devices section of Xcode's Organizer window (or use the Import button at the bottom of that window) to get Xcode to show you the symbolicated log file. The stack trace will then tell you what method was running when the crash happened, as well as the rest of the call chain that resulted in that method being called.

Comment: They sent me .plist files, and when I try to drag over devices or import it, nothing happens.

Comment: Check out [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7932992/643383) for a better description (with pictures!) of the process.