# How to debug "Terminating in response to backboardd's termination"

Tags: ios, objective-c, springboard

Currently I am working on app with huge images processing. Nothing unusual, but sometimes in complety random case my app is terminated due to backboardd crash. Without any errors, exceptions etc. I checked memory warings, nothing, no memory warnings at all, then I checked memory leaks with instruments, still nothing, then I checked backboard crash log ( http://pastebin.com/fk4DLwGL) I can not find any clue there.

What I can do more to track down this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found problem, in my app i made a custom side view controller implementation and I didn't queue animation actions for reveal a right and a left side view. That why i think spring board got crash (too many the same animations). I switched to similar open source controller with animation queue and now everything works.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to symbolicate that crash report I think as line 24: `4   backboardd                          0x000000010005ad60 0x100054000 + 28000` gives some info on the crash but its had the symbols stripped.

See [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/technotes/tn2151/_index.html) from Apple or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7932992/enabling-crash-logs-symbolication-in-xcode-4-2) answer for more information.

Comment: I made required setup, but crash log is completely the same. (http://pastebin.com/3VyGhrPp). Line 24 is still stripped `(4   backboardd 0x000000010000ed60 0x100008000 + 28000)`

Comment: When was the crash, while debugging or on the app store?