# iOS app crashes but crash logs has no relevant information

Tags: ios, crash-reports

I am getting this crash for my iOS app and it doesn't show any relevant file name (just shows main.m) that I can look at. Any pointers on what the issue could be?

```
Exception Type:             SIGSEGV
Exception Codes:            SEGV_ACCERR at 0x7ebf14b8
Crashed Thread:             0

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x3892860c objc_retain + 12
1   CoreData                            0x2defa915 -[NSFetchedResultsController(PrivateMethods) _managedObjectContextDidChange:] + 4013
2   CoreFoundation                      0x2e144f41 __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ + 13
3   CoreFoundation                      0x2e0b8da9 _CFXNotificationPost + 1721
4   Foundation                          0x2eaa3cc5 -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 73
5   CoreData                            0x2def994b -[NSManagedObjectContext(_NSInternalNotificationHandling) _postObjectsDidChangeNotificationWithUserInfo:] + 79
6   CoreData                            0x2def98e3 -[NSManagedObjectContext(_NSInternalChangeProcessing) _createAndPostChangeNotification:withDeletions:withUpdates:withRefreshes:] + 299
7   CoreData                            0x2def7f9f -[NSManagedObjectContext(_NSInternalChangeProcessing) _processRecentChanges:] + 2323
8   CoreData                            0x2df61c21 -[NSManagedObjectContext(_NestedContextSupport) _parentProcessSaveRequest:inContext:error:] + 1313
9   CoreData                            0x2df6256f __82-[NSManagedObjectContext(_NestedContextSupport) executeRequest:withContext:error:]_block_invoke + 563
10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x38e08b3b _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_slow_invoke + 71
11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x38e02d3f _dispatch_client_callout + 23
12  libdispatch.dylib                   0x38e056c3 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 279
13  CoreFoundation                      0x2e14d681 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 9
14  CoreFoundation                      0x2e14bf4d __CFRunLoopRun + 1309
15  CoreFoundation                      0x2e0b6769 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 525
16  CoreFoundation                      0x2e0b654b CFRunLoopRunInMode + 107
17  GraphicsServices                    0x330236d3 GSEventRunModal + 139
18  UIKit                               0x30a15891 UIApplicationMain + 1137
19  MyApp                               0x00034f7f main (main.m:18)
```

Comment: Could you show us some code ?

Comment: Looks like a memory issue. Can you recreate this crash while debugging the app in Xcode? Is so, turn on zombies and look for messages in the log about sending messages to deallocated objects.

Answer (score -1):

You need to enable the symbolication in order to see where the crash was caused in your code.

For further info check this [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2151/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008184-CH1-SECTION2) or this answer on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7932992/enabling-crash-logs-symbolication-in-xcode-4-2/7937300#7937300)

Comment: Look at the stack trace. The error is not in the app's code. It's coming from CoreData.

Comment: Yes it is coming from `CoreData` but no idea where abouts is the code causing the crash. He can either put break points, or enable symbolication the see the class name this crash is coming from. Just my opinion

Comment: His app is listed in the stack once - at the bottom - in `main`. You can't put breakpoints in CoreData and symbolicating won't give any more info about the app because the app isn't in the stack trace (other than `main`).