# Cannot understand iOS App Crash Log from iTunesConnect

Tags: ios, crash, app-store-connect, crash-reports

I have a new iOS App which was rejected by review center:

> 2.1 - Apps that crash will be rejected
>   2.1 Details
>
> > We were unable to review your app, as it crashed on launch. We have attached detailed crash logs to help troubleshoot this issue.

The .ipa file was exported by Product->Archieve-> Save for Ad Hoc Deployment.

I have tried install the .ipa on iPhone4、5、5s、6、6 plus even ipod Touch, iOS version including 7.0.x - 8.3 (target device is above 7.0), all of them work fine.

They also send me an crash log, but I could not locate the problem. 
Following is the full crash log (Hardware Model is 'xxx'), Please help..

```
Incident Identifier: 32CE3807-D70D-45F9-BE0B-C87EFC725901
CrashReporter Key:   0b20b25bf737f71a82be3b21f57f3dd3a46ee468
Hardware Model:      xxx
Process:             MyApp [1227]
Path:    /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/4FDE6559-260E-4EBB-A3E0-02B84BE90B5C/MyApp.app/MyApp
Identifier:          com.mydomain
Version:             112 (1.0.0)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2015-04-13 18:03:47.966 -0700
Launch Time:         2015-04-13 18:02:33.282 -0700
OS Version:          iOS 8.3 (12F69)
Report Version:      105

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Triggered by Thread:  0

Last Exception Backtrace:
(0x1827382d8 0x193e580e4 0x18273f3a4 0x18273c154 0x18263eccc 0x1002534a4 0x1001e5098 0x100259f3c 0x100259968 0x100251fac 0x187175760 0x186abde1c 0x186ab8884 0x186ab8728 0x186ab7ebc 0x186ab7c3c 0x18716c56c 0x1826f02a4 0x1826ed230 0x1826ed610 0x1826192d4 0x18bd076fc 0x1871defac 0x10013ae14 0x1944d6a08)

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001945ef270 0x1945d4000 + 111216

1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019468d16c 0x194688000 + 20844
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x0000000194566b14 0x194504000 + 404244
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000193625414 0x193624000 + 5140
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000193641bcc 0x193624000 + 121804
5   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000193641474 0x193624000 + 119924
6   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x0000000193e58200 0x193e50000 + 33280
7   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018273f3a0 0x182610000 + 1242016
8   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018273c150 0x182610000 + 1229136
9   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018263ecc8 0x182610000 + 191688
10  YES                             0x00000001002534a0 0x1000a0000 + 1782944
11  YES                             0x00000001001e5094 0x1000a0000 + 1331348
12  YES                             0x0000000100259f38 0x1000a0000 + 1810232
13  YES                             0x0000000100259964 0x1000a0000 + 1808740
14  YES                             0x0000000100251fa8 0x1000a0000 + 1777576
15  UIKit                           0x000000018717575c 0x187168000 + 55132
16  QuartzCore                      0x0000000186abde18 0x186ab0000 + 56856
17  QuartzCore                      0x0000000186ab8880 0x186ab0000 + 34944
18  QuartzCore                      0x0000000186ab8724 0x186ab0000 + 34596
19  QuartzCore                      0x0000000186ab7eb8 0x186ab0000 + 32440
20  QuartzCore                      0x0000000186ab7c38 0x186ab0000 + 31800
21  UIKit                           0x000000018716c568 0x187168000 + 17768
22  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001826f02a0 0x182610000 + 918176
23  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001826ed22c 0x182610000 + 905772
24  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001826ed60c 0x182610000 + 906764
25  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001826192d0 0x182610000 + 37584
26  GraphicsServices                0x000000018bd076f8 0x18bcfc000 + 46840
27  UIKit                           0x00000001871defa8 0x187168000 + 487336
28  YES                             0x000000010013ae10 0x1000a0000 + 634384
29  libdyld.dylib                   0x00000001944d6a04 0x1944d4000 + 10756

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001945d4c24 0x1945d4000 + 3108
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001944b9e6c 0x1944a8000 + 73324
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001944ab998 0x1944a8000 + 14744

Thread 2 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001945d4e0c 0x1945d4000 + 3596
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001945d4c84 0x1945d4000 + 3204
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001826ef720 0x182610000 + 915232
3   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001826ed674 0x182610000 + 906868
4   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001826192d0 0x182610000 + 37584
5   CFNetwork                       0x00000001820fa890 0x18205c000 + 649360
6   Foundation                      0x0000000183639db4 0x183544000 + 1007028
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019468bdc4 0x194688000 + 15812
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019468bd20 0x194688000 + 15648
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000194688ef4 0x194688000 + 3828

Thread 3 name:  AFNetworking
Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001945d4e0c 0x1945d4000 + 3596
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001945d4c84 0x1945d4000 + 3204
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001826ef720 0x182610000 + 915232
3   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001826ed674 0x182610000 + 906868
4   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001826192d0 0x182610000 + 37584
5   Foundation                      0x00000001835514c4 0x183544000 + 54468
6   Foundation                      0x00000001835ab80c 0x183544000 + 423948
7   YES                             0x0000000100201ad0 0x1000a0000 + 1448656
8   Foundation                      0x0000000183639db4 0x183544000 + 1007028
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019468bdc4 0x194688000 + 15812
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019468bd20 0x194688000 + 15648
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000194688ef4 0x194688000 + 3828

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001945d4e0c 0x1945d4000 + 3596
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001945d4c84 0x1945d4000 + 3204
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001826ef720 0x182610000 + 915232
3   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001826ed674 0x182610000 + 906868
4   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001826192d0 0x182610000 + 37584
5   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018266b358 0x182610000 + 373592
6   CoreMotion                      0x0000000183024364 0x182fdc000 + 295780
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019468bdc4 0x194688000 + 15812
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019468bd20 0x194688000 + 15648
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000194688ef4 0x194688000 + 3828

Thread 5 name:  com.apple.CFSocket.private
Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001945ef498 0x1945d4000 + 111768
1   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001826f5124 0x182610000 + 938276
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019468bdc4 0x194688000 + 15812
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019468bd20 0x194688000 + 15648
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000194688ef4 0x194688000 + 3828

Thread 6 name:  WebThread
Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001945d4e0c 0x1945d4000 + 3596
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001945d4c84 0x1945d4000 + 3204
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001826ef720 0x182610000 + 915232
3   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001826ed674 0x182610000 + 906868
4   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001826192d0 0x182610000 + 37584
5   WebCore                         0x0000000190d08890 0x190c58000 + 723088
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019468bdc4 0x194688000 + 15812
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019468bd20 0x194688000 + 15648
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000194688ef4 0x194688000 + 3828

Thread 7 name:  JavaScriptCore::BlockFree
Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001945ef078 0x1945d4000 + 110712
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019468af28 0x194688000 + 12072
2   libc++.1.dylib                  0x00000001935d4cac 0x1935cc000 + 36012
3   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000183c0d620 0x183bf4000 + 103968
4   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000183c08b9c 0x183bf4000 + 84892
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019468bdc4 0x194688000 + 15812
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019468bd20 0x194688000 + 15648
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000194688ef4 0x194688000 + 3828

Thread 8 name:  JavaScriptCore::Marking
Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001945ef078 0x1945d4000 + 110712
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019468af28 0x194688000 + 12072
2   libc++.1.dylib                  0x00000001935d4cac 0x1935cc000 + 36012
3   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000183eb6edc 0x183bf4000 + 2895580
4   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000183eb6f80 0x183bf4000 + 2895744
5   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000183c08b9c 0x183bf4000 + 84892
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019468bdc4 0x194688000 + 15812
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019468bd20 0x194688000 + 15648
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000194688ef4 0x194688000 + 3828

Thread 9 name:  JavaScriptCore::Marking
Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001945ef078 0x1945d4000 + 110712
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019468af28 0x194688000 + 12072
2   libc++.1.dylib                  0x00000001935d4cac 0x1935cc000 + 36012
3   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000183eb6edc 0x183bf4000 + 2895580
4   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000183eb6f80 0x183bf4000 + 2895744
5   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000183c08b9c 0x183bf4000 + 84892
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019468bdc4 0x194688000 + 15812
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019468bd20 0x194688000 + 15648
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000194688ef4 0x194688000 + 3828

Thread 10 name:  WebCore: CFNetwork Loader
Thread 10:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001945d4e0c 0x1945d4000 + 3596
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001945d4c84 0x1945d4000 + 3204
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001826ef720 0x182610000 + 915232
3   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001826ed674 0x182610000 + 906868
4   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001826192d0 0x182610000 + 37584
5   WebCore                         0x0000000190d3c9ac 0x190c58000 + 936364
6   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000183c08b9c 0x183bf4000 + 84892
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019468bdc4 0x194688000 + 15812
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019468bd20 0x194688000 + 15648
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000194688ef4 0x194688000 + 3828

Thread 11 name:  Dispatch queue: 
NSOperationQueue 0x17043da60 :: NSOperation 0x17811ef00 (QOS: USER_INITIATED)
Thread 11:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001945d4e0c 0x1945d4000 + 3596
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001945d4c84 0x1945d4000 + 3204
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001826ef720 0x182610000 + 915232
3   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001826ed674 0x182610000 + 906868
4   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001826192d0 0x182610000 + 37584
5   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018266b358 0x182610000 + 373592
6   YES                             0x000000010027b5fc 0x1000a0000 + 1947132
7   Foundation                      0x0000000183621f24 0x183544000 + 909092
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001944a9950 0x1944a8000 + 6480
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001944b40a0 0x1944a8000 + 49312
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001944aca58 0x1944a8000 + 19032
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001944b6314 0x1944a8000 + 58132
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001944b7c48 0x1944a8000 + 64584
13  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000194689228 0x194688000 + 4648
14  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000194688eec 0x194688000 + 3820

Thread 12:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001945efc78 0x1945d4000 + 113784
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001946892d8 0x194688000 + 4824
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000194688eec 0x194688000 + 3820

Thread 13 name:  
Dispatch queue: NSOperationQueue 0x17043da60 :: NSOperation 0x170307f20 
(QOS:     USER_INITIATED)
Thread 13:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001945d4e0c 0x1945d4000 + 3596
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001945d4c84 0x1945d4000 + 3204
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001826ef720 0x182610000 + 915232
3   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001826ed674 0x182610000 + 906868
4   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001826192d0 0x182610000 + 37584
5   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018266b358 0x182610000 + 373592
6   YES                             0x000000010027b5fc 0x1000a0000 + 1947132
7   Foundation                      0x0000000183621f24 0x183544000 + 909092
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001944a9950 0x1944a8000 + 6480
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001944b40a0 0x1944a8000 + 49312
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001944aca58 0x1944a8000 + 19032
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001944b6314 0x1944a8000 + 58132
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001944b7c48 0x1944a8000 + 64584
13  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000194689228 0x194688000 + 4648
14  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000194688eec 0x194688000 + 3820

Thread 14:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001945efc78 0x1945d4000 + 113784
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001946892d8 0x194688000 + 4824
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000194688eec 0x194688000 + 3820

Thread 15:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001945efc78 0x1945d4000 + 113784
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001946892d8 0x194688000 + 4824
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000194688eec 0x194688000 + 3820

Thread 16:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001945efc78 0x1945d4000 + 113784
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001946892d8 0x194688000 + 4824
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000194688eec 0x194688000 + 3820

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000000000000   x1: 0x0000000000000000   x2: 0x0000000000000000   x3: 0x00000001702ee431
    x4: 0x0000000193645b89   x5: 0x000000016fd5c0e0   x6: 0x000000000000006e   x7: 0x0000000000000002
    x8: 0x0000000008000000   x9: 0x0000000004000000  x10: 0x0000000000000200  x11: 0x000000016fd5bcb2
   x12: 0x0000000000000000  x13: 0x0000000000000000  x14: 0x0000000000000000  x15: 0x0000000000000000
   x16: 0x0000000000000148  x17: 0x0000000193e7239c  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000000000006
   x20: 0x000000019843f310  x21: 0x0000000198427ce8  x22: 0x000000017020a700  x23: 0x0000000100bb8a08
   x24: 0x0000000000000000  x25: 0x000000018797e2d0  x26: 0x00000001879527d1  x27: 0x0000000000000000
   x28: 0x00000001984260a8  fp: 0x000000016fd5c040   lr: 0x000000019468d170
    sp: 0x000000016fd5c020   pc: 0x00000001945ef270 cpsr: 0x00000000

Binary Images:
0x1000a0000 - 0x100957fff YES arm64  <46445f64c0ea339f8853fdf0f8493c35> /var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/4FDE6559-260E-4EBB-A3E0-02B84BE90B5C/YES.app/YES
0x12009c000 - 0x1200c3fff dyld arm64  <75c68bbe28b13fcd91014f15139742dc> /usr/lib/dyld
0x180d14000 - 0x180e0efff RawCamera arm64  <ebb36059ba8a3c1d8caba3cbfa039d63> /System/Library/CoreServices/RawCamera.bundle/RawCamera
0x180e2c000 - 0x180ec9fff AGXGLDriver arm64  <e853a6d23bc33b6891e845f0794ddfce> /System/Library/Extensions/AGXGLDriver.bundle/AGXGLDriver
0x180ee4000 - 0x181078fff AVFoundation arm64  <c69cb19d6db0339bbfb4c18fa7f4f26c> /System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/AVFoundation
0x18107c000 - 0x1810e0fff libAVFAudio.dylib arm64  <fdd31b28c0ec3f76b8f0fa9a057e43d9> /System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/libAVFAudio.dylib
0x181124000 - 0x181124fff Accelerate arm64  <a2161063fee1315193bc488d0354f43e> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate
0x18113c000 - 0x18135bfff vImage arm64  <74eb7b77dbcd321db86e784be9353a08> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vImage.framework/vImage
0x18135c000 - 0x181403fff libBLAS.dylib arm64  <56e8b79c2c03379dad45fe2ea1a4052f> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBLAS.dylib
0x181404000 - 0x18177efff libLAPACK.dylib arm64  <fd491ae19b12315babb621650a0eef76> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLAPACK.dylib
0x181780000 - 0x181795fff libLinearAlgebra.dylib arm64  <9307063a5e1833abbb857a9ec4c5369e> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLinearAlgebra.dylib
0x181798000 - 0x181800fff libvDSP.dylib arm64  <d4d2b4a941213e2b81f3ddafd6b8a312> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvDSP.dylib
0x181804000 - 0x181827fff libvMisc.dylib arm64  <92a0dd635be43dfe8c128c888ef37c0e> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvMisc.dylib
0x181828000 - 0x181828fff vecLib arm64  <9248f57f1d8430219a810aa93254f157> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/vecLib
0x18182c000 - 0x18185bfff Accounts arm64  <4199851056d4376aa4d8668b83c85454> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accounts.framework/Accounts
0x18185c000 - 0x18185cfff AdSupport arm64  <f172a17bdc2e3bd19b952a69e0021450> /System/Library/Frameworks/AdSupport.framework/AdSupport
0x181860000 - 0x1818defff AddressBook arm64  <73735c2a294139e5b99ada613fc861ea> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBook.framework/AddressBook
0x1818e0000 - 0x181a33fff AddressBookUI arm64  <860bc29210ba3d7c80dc83a83388e31c> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBookUI.framework/AddressBookUI
0x181a34000 - 0x181a48fff AssetsLibrary arm64  <06c85b7fcfaf3722b6e7a89a1ed5559e> /System/Library/Frameworks/AssetsLibrary.framework/AssetsLibrary
0x181bfc000 - 0x181ebcfff AudioToolbox arm64  <760c2dc59fa13660a769cc1b052d41e6> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox
0x18205c000 - 0x18226ffff CFNetwork arm64  <df5535d1633f375aa889f755db0a93b9> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
0x182270000 - 0x18230cfff CloudKit arm64  <c24c6a0eeb1a38b598fafc24e9974595> /System/Library/Frameworks/CloudKit.framework/CloudKit
0x182310000 - 0x182375fff CoreAudio arm64  <b85ca2cdb29639ccb5f6405baf597027> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/CoreAudio
0x18239c000 - 0x1823bdfff CoreBluetooth arm64  <fbd7cbc4b2533ea38844bf98757ce58d> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreBluetooth.framework/CoreBluetooth
0x1823c0000 - 0x18260cfff CoreData arm64  <af13d4e830e13607b745fe57f90e5d5e> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreData.framework/CoreData
0x182610000 - 0x18296efff CoreFoundation arm64  <6548b13bef1f3f958d96266f7c4c44e0> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
0x182970000 - 0x182ad2fff CoreGraphics arm64  <92162d42d08d357ab66302a38d724828> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
0x182b28000 - 0x182b2afff libCGXType.A.dylib arm64  <8f40b7d9b97b344f9c7a5a0b79bdc2b7> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libCGXType.A.dylib
0x182b2c000 - 0x182b37fff libCMSBuiltin.A.dylib arm64  <a40d7bdbbe6c3317bcf4c20c085df848> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libCMSBuiltin.A.dylib
0x182d2c000 - 0x182d4afff libRIP.A.dylib arm64  <975284709e51353690ec8a651b43c1db> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libRIP.A.dylib
0x182d4c000 - 0x182e7efff CoreImage arm64  <d7a2122dc8173803bc220fde3cfebfdf> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreImage.framework/CoreImage
0x182e80000 - 0x182edefff CoreLocation arm64  <a166ad7f12f93406b54ae6a170fb38ee> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreLocation.framework/CoreLocation
0x182f18000 - 0x182fdbfff CoreMedia arm64  <403a9798401c3b70a207e0e236454c0d> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMedia.framework/CoreMedia
0x182fdc000 - 0x1830cafff CoreMotion arm64  <61338e072f2a385ab4e315975f23eea2> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMotion.framework/CoreMotion
0x1830cc000 - 0x18313dfff CoreTelephony arm64  <d9adf384d64d30319eac8e8711ede892> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony
0x183140000 - 0x183248fff CoreText arm64  <4a9633cee0393585a98fcf07410e0828> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/CoreText
0x18324c000 - 0x183269fff CoreVideo arm64  <217e5b69f6d03f8893f01de3e40915a8> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/CoreVideo
0x18326c000 - 0x183390fff EventKit arm64  <f7af75b17dac3c5aa8dc91a1edd1df37> /System/Library/Frameworks/EventKit.framework/EventKit
0x183544000 - 0x18379cfff Foundation arm64  <509b484fb7b634b19673d50296d8278f> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
0x1837d0000 - 0x1837f9fff GSS arm64  <3dae218853563b1a985b80d6a353bad8> /System/Library/Frameworks/GSS.framework/GSS
0x1838e4000 - 0x18394ffff IOKit arm64  <311bed1f2b893195b8c0564d8925bfa2> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
0x183950000 - 0x183bf3fff ImageIO arm64  <7d3c81746f2c3f1488b3efc633d21633> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO
0x183bf4000 - 0x184095fff JavaScriptCore arm64  <1ad0ed311f3e3897bac70f3388fc05be> /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore
0x1848b4000 - 0x1849cdfff MapKit arm64  <0bb8a0be8c883fcc84d0453858c8e083> /System/Library/Frameworks/MapKit.framework/MapKit
0x1849d0000 - 0x1849d6fff MediaAccessibility arm64  <4e3e82a2b09a38fcbf01843f97d5e604> /System/Library/Frameworks/MediaAccessibility.framework/MediaAccessibility
0x1849d8000 - 0x184bfbfff MediaPlayer arm64  <fb0500c5695c36b5b54865f533cc899e> /System/Library/Frameworks/MediaPlayer.framework/MediaPlayer
0x184bfc000 - 0x18501afff MediaToolbox arm64  <c2103a7dd16e3f67abfe898b039061e7> /System/Library/Frameworks/MediaToolbox.framework/MediaToolbox
0x18501c000 - 0x1850f0fff MessageUI arm64  <000bbe6f4a8c32bda9c8ea674a7f200d> /System/Library/Frameworks/MessageUI.framework/MessageUI
0x1850f4000 - 0x18516cfff Metal arm64  <eb54636e26cd3dee870fa5e4fb708fe6> /System/Library/Frameworks/Metal.framework/Metal
0x185170000 - 0x185221fff MobileCoreServices arm64  <daa61b358c17365792c20df791224e26> /System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices
0x185284000 - 0x185339fff NetworkExtension arm64  <4389ce2ecabb3c0eb3cc04889fe937c4> /System/Library/Frameworks/NetworkExtension.framework/NetworkExtension
0x1863a4000 - 0x186499fff GLEngine arm64  <3a58df00302d33d9a41c77fdfc47cdb5> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/GLEngine.bundle/GLEngine
0x18649c000 - 0x1864a6fff OpenGLES arm64  <8824bb82d43937a9b0aa3870ece35772> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/OpenGLES
0x1864ac000 - 0x1864adfff libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib arm64  <34760639fb2331dcaa229ba0e418c1af> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib
0x1864b0000 - 0x1864b3fff libCoreFSCache.dylib arm64  <e6f967504d5937d59223598de12969ab> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCoreFSCache.dylib
0x1864b4000 - 0x1864b8fff libCoreVMClient.dylib arm64  <30969b8fde9f36c4a6a0293c03e74e5f> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCoreVMClient.dylib
0x1864bc000 - 0x1864c6fff libGFXShared.dylib arm64  <5942ea8060c63e86b3ffbfb76b061276> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGFXShared.dylib
0x1864c8000 - 0x186513fff libGLImage.dylib arm64  <3e46a6b44be93e5689e4851c76b2db04> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLImage.dylib
0x186514000 - 0x18668ffff libGLProgrammability.dylib arm64  <7234615bc05e369dafdca253e5f8a88a> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLProgrammability.dylib
0x186ab0000 - 0x186c42fff QuartzCore arm64  <e47923f08f343c3e98e77f22f674f234> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore
0x186c44000 - 0x186c90fff QuickLook arm64  <c7ce94fecae33d839b804000f2ecca60> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuickLook.framework/QuickLook
0x186ec8000 - 0x186f1cfff Security arm64  <80b60ba1feba39afb6686e342398cce1> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
0x1870d4000 - 0x1870ecfff StoreKit arm64  <cdb93be75f683059be5c4a107ba4c653> /System/Library/Frameworks/StoreKit.framework/StoreKit
0x1870f0000 - 0x187163fff SystemConfiguration arm64  <633d8a8abeaf3abda9b0401146f2b668> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
0x187168000 - 0x187ae8fff UIKit arm64  <f67965f71974303e90cfaed997ae36a3> /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
0x187aec000 - 0x187b65fff VideoToolbox arm64  <1468c96c3448370bbb407644bedbb368> /System/Library/Frameworks/VideoToolbox.framework/VideoToolbox
0x187ba0000 - 0x187e04fff WebKit arm64  <5e03a0bc7ab436ba900562cceb681ef4> /System/Library/Frameworks/WebKit.framework/WebKit
0x1881b4000 - 0x1881b7fff AGXCompilerConnection arm64  <f2c0eda0be5136338d09c22ba3522277> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AGXCompilerConnection.framework/AGXCompilerConnection
0x18822c000 - 0x188239fff AOSNotification arm64  <bfc45391892b3510ac92ba9362e5100c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AOSNotification.framework/AOSNotification
0x1883d4000 - 0x188432fff AccountsDaemon arm64  <e819e315efce3a178391a7dfbee95db0> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AccountsDaemon.framework/AccountsDaemon
0x18845c000 - 0x188461fff AggregateDictionary arm64  <cfa106cd07b430a6959f9127a6c3363a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AggregateDictionary.framework/AggregateDictionary
0x188664000 - 0x188667fff AirPlaySupport arm64  <9379098c9eed33088c7096882eec570d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AirPlaySupport.framework/AirPlaySupport
0x1888bc000 - 0x188904fff AppSupport arm64  <d088c6263b4932aebd9dcf2a14aadef2> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSupport.framework/AppSupport
0x188908000 - 0x188963fff AppleAccount arm64  <0374ffa0f0563b108aa7a58f2c72f39f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppleAccount.framework/AppleAccount
0x188a74000 - 0x188ac0fff AppleJPEG arm64  <621fe1223e9038a09023dd6c558ce423> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppleJPEG.framework/AppleJPEG
0x188ad4000 - 0x188ae8fff ApplePushService arm64  <38b2aec9a5b5357aa8e1060d28992da3> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ApplePushService.framework/ApplePushService
0x188aec000 - 0x188af5fff AppleSRP arm64  <8f0cacbeabdf39b3815a72e7ec9e8668> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppleSRP.framework/AppleSRP
0x188b08000 - 0x188b13fff AssertionServices arm64  <e0f182c7fdcd34a1a4acfe0bd4c7eae3> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssertionServices.framework/AssertionServices
0x188b14000 - 0x188b31fff AssetsLibraryServices arm64  <e28e74aed7103573b9416e016525ac04> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices
0x188b34000 - 0x188b74fff AssistantServices arm64  <f8cc50774cbf3007bd3944592b1608e8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssistantServices.framework/AssistantServices
0x188bb0000 - 0x188bb3fff BTLEAudioController arm64  <ea2ff306f28638ca8bc7a4f02d3c8f1e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BTLEAudioController.framework/BTLEAudioController
0x188bb4000 - 0x188bd0fff BackBoardServices arm64  <ff372ac34d6430829a97778caad5bdf4> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BackBoardServices.framework/BackBoardServices
0x188bd8000 - 0x188c15fff BaseBoard arm64  <ab16c3464cfb3319bf31202639bb4a90> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BaseBoard.framework/BaseBoard
0x188c38000 - 0x188c68fff Bom arm64  <45c2562173063fb2bd0e71bbc3423915> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Bom.framework/Bom
0x188d18000 - 0x188d21fff CacheDelete arm64  <c5cb9203a779314ea5616b6cb35c39a0> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CacheDelete.framework/CacheDelete
0x188d74000 - 0x188da4fff CalendarFoundation arm64  <ce2278a234d0300a8e1c55d93179a8ea>
```

....and so on...
exceed stackoverflow limit

Comment: Start by symbolicating the crash log so you can see where in your code the problem is happening.

Answer (score 1):

Try these steps to analyze crash report from apple:

1. Copy the release .app file which was pushed to the AppStore, the .dSYM file that was created at the time of release and the crash report you received from Apple into a **folder**.
2. **open** **terminal** application and go to the folder created above (using `cd` command)
3. Run **atos -arch armv7 -o APPNAME.app/APPNAME MEMORY_LOCATION_OF_CRASH**. The memory location should be the one at which the app crashed as per the report.

Ex:  **atos -arch armv7  -o 'APPNAME.app'/'APPNAME' 0x0003b508**

This would show you the exact line, method name which resulted in crash.

Ex: [classname functionName:]; -510

**Symbolicating IPA**

if we use IPA for symbolicating - just rename the extention .ipa with .zip, extract it then we can get a Payload Folder which contain app. In this case we don't need .dSYM file.

**Note**

This can only work if the app binary does not have symbols stripped. By default release builds stripped the symbols. We can change it in project build settings "Strip Debug Symbols During Copy" to NO.

More details see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7932992/enabling-crash-logs-symbolication-in-xcode-4-2/7937300#7937300)

Comment: Unfortunately, I used the default settings of "Strip Debug Symbols During Copy". Now I have changed it to "NO", but I still cannot understand the crash log.

Comment: Refer this url : http://www.raywenderlich.com/23704/demystifying-ios-application-crash-logs

Comment: & another url: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AnalyzingCrashReports/AnalyzingCrashReports.html