# Xcode 7 crash logs not symbolicated

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift, crash-reports

Hej Folks,

I know that many questions and answers exists here to this topic but no one helps me with my questions...

I have different Xcode projects (Swift/Objective-C), both projects are available on the AppStore and how it goes, the apps crashed sometimes.

Now with the wonderful (but in my case not working) Xcode 7 features crash logs will be summarised from Xcode, but all crash logs are not symbolicated. I know that I can symbolicate with the "symbolicatecrash"-tool and the atos command. But why the hell does Xcode that not for me?

I read many questions and answers here, also that one ([Enabling crash logs symbolication in Xcode 4.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7932992/enabling-crash-logs-symbolication-in-xcode-4-2/7937300#7937300)) and therefore I ask myself if I have misconfigured build-settings!?

My build settings differs (to that given answer) in the settings "Deployment Postprocessing", "Use Separate Strip" and "Strip Debug Symbols during copy". But I don't want to deliver debug-Symbols in my release build (Security by obfuscation ;) )!

Can anybody bring some light into which Settings I have to set that the automatic symbolication of crash logs works with Xcode 7? I can't find any hint directly from apple, which settings are therefore necessary.

By AppStore submission the "Include app symbols for symbolication..."-Checkbox is already checked! The Bitcode checkbox is disabled.

I'm very thankful for any helpful hint...

My environment:
Xcode 7.2
Mac OS X Yosemite (10.10.5)