# Xcode cannot symbolicate my crash logs even though I have correct .dSYM file

Tags: ios, xcode, crash, symbolicatecrash, xcarchive

I have been observing this that when ever my app crashes i get the crash log and try to symbolicate it but following happen

1. When I use xcode to symbolicate, it never symbolicates the addresses of the crash
2. When I use atos command specified [developer.apple.com technotes](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2151/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008184-CH1-SYMBOLICATE_WITH_ATOS) it either gives some other class function name that does not have to do any thing with the crash
3. I have used other methods like symbolicatecrash script but the result is same as before.
4. I also tried solution given [stackoverflow.com/questions/7932992](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7932992/enabling-crash-logs-symbolication-in-xcode-4-2/7937300#7937300) but did not succeed
5. I created a demo crash and tried to change my scheme of the app for "Run" and changed "build configuration" to "release" to check if the crashes symbolicate when I run the app directly to device, I test the app, the demo crash occurs and in this case the crahes get symbolicated.
6. I created a demo crash in a new app and created an archive and export IPA, used this ipa in a device to recreate that crash but still xcode could not symbolicate that crash.

I don't get why is it behaving this way,

I looked into the archives to find my dSYM file and can locate it there but could not symbolicate it using any of the processes stated above.

**A guidance will be helpful!**

Comment: Make sure the UUID of your binary in the crash report is the same as the UUID of the dSYM. Looks like it is not. Other reason could be that in your manual `atos` call you don't provide the load address of the binary to `atos`

Comment: Thanks for the reply @kerni but I checked the UUID was correct and I am using atos command the same way apple described [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2151/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008184-CH1-SYMBOLICATE_WITH_ATOS) where i added the address to binary and then address to crash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was working with code back to see if there can be any impact of bitcode with help of a friend, found that while exporting archive to IPA, it asks me to rebuild with bitcode (which was checked) I just tried and unchecked it to create the IPA and this time my app crash logs were symbolicated, I still don't know why this happens because apple recomends to rebuild with bitcode while submitting apps.
I am looking for more answeres for why is it happening?
Will keep you posted (also a enlighten me if there are any misses.)